# Laravel + Vuejs: How to create a link to a blade template from Vuejs Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to keep Login and Register in blade. I used the default `php artisan ui vue --auth`.
Then keep the SPA in Vuejs with Vuetify.

App.vue

```js
...sidebar containing link to register
            <v-list-item link @click="register">
                <v-list-item-action><v-icon>mdi-icon</v-icon></v-list-item-action>
                <v-list-item-content><v-list-item-title>Register</v-list-item-title></v-list-item-content>
            </v-list-item>
...

<script>
        methods: {
            register() {
                axios.post('/register')
                    .finally( err => {
                        window.location = '/register';
                    })
            },
        }
</script>
```

If you click the register link, it keeps going to "/home" instead of "/register". Help please thanks.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
window.location = '/register';
```

use this

```
window.location.href = '/register';
```